# Why the whole page is re-rendering when i change the range slider in react?

Tags: reactjs

[This is the gif of re-rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhIUI.gif)

When I slide the range slider after selecting a video, the whole page re-renders, how to avoid this problem? How to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of a component? I am using react hooks. I am placing a range slider inside the form element. I am using React Dropzone to use drag and drop facility.The setVideo state is passed to ReactDropZone component.I don't understand why this is happening

Here code is,

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import ReactDropZone from '../ReactDropZone';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import { fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

const Compress = ({ ffmpeg }) => {
    const [videoFile, setVideoFile] = useState();
    const [rangeInputVal, setRangeInputVal] = useState(1);
    const [progressVisibility, setProgressVisibility] = useState(false);
    const [completedNow, setCompletedNow] = useState(0);
    const [convertedVideo, setConvertedVideo] = useState();

    const convertFun = async num => {
        // Write the file to memory
        ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'test.mp4', await fetchFile(videoFile));

        // Run the FFMpeg command
        await ffmpeg.run('-i', 'test.mp4', '-crf', `${num}`, 'out.mp4');

        // Read the result
        const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'out.mp4');

        // Create a URL
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
        setConvertedVideo(url);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        ffmpeg.setProgress(({ ratio }) => {
            console.log('completed now is', parseFloat(ratio) * 100);
            setCompletedNow(Math.round(parseFloat(ratio) * 100));
        });
    }, []);

    const handleRangeInput = e => {
        setRangeInputVal(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleCancelBtn = () => {
        setVideoFile(null);
    };

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setTimeout(() => {
            setProgressVisibility(true);
        }, 200);

        convertFun(e.target.range.value);

        console.log(e.target.range.value);
    };

    console.log('compress video:-', videoFile);

    return (
        <div className="compress">
            <div className="compress__container">
                <Row className="align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <Col md={12} sm={12} lg={6} className="fileuploader__area">
                        {videoFile ? (
                            <figure>
                                <video controls src={URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)} />
                                <button className="cancelVideo" onClick={handleCancelBtn}>
                                    X
                                </button>
                            </figure>
                        ) : (
                            <ReactDropZone setVideoFile={setVideoFile} />
                        )}
                    </Col>

                    <Col md={12} sm={12} lg={6}>
                        <div className="compress__content">
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Form.Group className="choose__quality">
                                    <Form.Label>choose quality:-</Form.Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="range"
                                        min="1"
                                        max="50"
                                        name="range"
                                        value={rangeInputVal}
                                        onChange={handleRangeInput}
                                    />
                                    <span>{rangeInputVal && rangeInputVal}</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <p>(higher the value,smaller the size)</p>
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group>
                                    <button
                                        disabled={videoFile ? false : true}
                                        style={{ opacity: videoFile ? 1 : 0.5 }}
                                        type="submit"
                                        className="customBtn customBtn__small">
                                        Start conversion
                                    </button>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </form>

                            <Form.Group>
                                {progressVisibility && (
                                    <ProgressBar animated now={completedNow} label={`${completedNow} %`} />
                                )}
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group className="download__video">
                                {completedNow === 100 && (
                                    <p>
                                        Video is successfully converted.{' '}
                                        <a
                                            href={convertedVideo}
                                            className="downloadLink"
                                            download={`${videoFile && videoFile.name}`}>
                                            Click here to download
                                        </a>{' '}
                                    </p>
                                )}
                            </Form.Group>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Compress;
```

Answer (score 0):

The component is supposed to re-render when the state changes, so calling "setRangeInputVal", for example, will re-render the component. Something that might be worth a try is putting the code for the video in its own component and wrapping it with React's memo HOC.

```
const Video = React.memo((videoFile, handleCancelBtn) => {
    return <figure>
        <video controls src={URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)} />
        <button className="cancelVideo" onClick={handleCancelBtn}>
            X
        </button>
    </figure> 
});
```

Using the memo HOC, if the props passed to the component have not changed from the last render, React will skip rendering that component. More information on this can be found in React's documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts. Is React.memo and useMemo are both same?

Comment: I am now getting this error , TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

Comment: Even after trying  React.memo ,page is still re-rendering